# Deleting a node in a B-Tree - using inorder Predecessor vs. Successor as the replacement key

Tags: binary-search-tree, b-tree

Suppose I wanted to delete 70 from the tree using inorder Predecessor as the replacement key and then after that using inorder Successor as the replacement key.

[image]

What would be the difference between the two?

Comment: Probably better suited for [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Your username scared me a bit xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: deletion using inorder Predecessor]

This is deletion of 70 using inorder Predecessor
[image: deletion using inorder Succesor]

This is deletion of 70 using inorder Successor